# How to fetch values stored in custom mapping fields in elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch

The elasticsearch (1.7) index I am dealing with has a property "title" which has many custom field mappings each having an analyser. How to fetch the data stored in these individual fields?

```
 title.std
 title.stp
```

Here's the mappings data.

```
 "mappings": {
  "myindex": {
    "_all": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "standard",
        "fields": {
          "std": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "standard"
          },
          "stp": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "stop"
          }
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: You can give the [term vectors API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/docs-termvectors.html) a try.

Comment: Awesome! You should provide it as an answer so I can upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [term vectors API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/docs-termvectors.html) in order to return information and statistics on terms in the fields of a particular document.

You'd invoke the endpoint like this:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/1/_termvector?pretty=true' -d '{
  "fields" : ["title.std", "title.stp"],
  "offsets" : true,
  "payloads" : true,
  "positions" : true,
  "term_statistics" : true,
  "field_statistics" : true
}'
```